# oauth2 create a library based on client-oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, gitea

Please tell me how it is possible, based on the ready-made client-oauth2 library, to create your own library with settings for authorization and authentication via gitea or keycloack, that is, to immediately redirect to gitea or keycloack?
More detailed steps if possible.
PS - just started to figure it out)

Comment: Hi js8dev. Please, describe your needs better. oauth2-provider for Gitea already exists: https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/oauth2-provider/